# switch from HDD to SSD

Tags: 20.04, hard-drive, ssd

I want to replace my HDD with SSD since I can't use both because my laptop has only 1 slot. I am totally confused about how to transfer the whole HDD data to SSD along with the Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Why bother transferring the OS? One easy, safe, reasonably fast option is to simply clean-install on the SSD, then copy your data across. You will (obviously) need to copy your data to some other media before removing the HDD.

Comment: Could also get an external enclosure for hard drive and connect by USB.  Have speed of SSD and extra space of HD for data.